# SQL - not null or condition

Tags: sql

I'm quite new to SQL and am facing the following problem.
Consider we have a table with two columns:

```
A         B
10        20
NULL      15
25        10
50        30
NULL      100
```

What I need is to select rows which satisfy the following conditions:

either
1) A is NULL
or
2) A < B

Which means, as a result I want to see such table:

```
A         B
10        20
NULL      15
NULL      100
```

I tried to use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE A < B OR A is NULL
```

But it seems like it doesn't work the way I supposed it to.

How should a correct query look like?
Thank you!

Comment: What's the type of column A and B? It seems odd that you have both strings and numbers in column A.

Comment: Null or None ? BTW, Is this SQL Server or MySQL ?

Comment: Does none mean Null? is your data text or numeric?  `where coalesce(A,0) < B maybe` if we assume a is NULL when none above. ?

Comment: Actually, data is timestamp, I just decided to give a numeric example to keep it simple. By None I meant NULL, sorry for inexactitude. Edited.

Comment: Why doesn't the query you posted work? Which results did you get?

Comment: Now I guess the problem is that I have conditions on other columns (they are more than two, actually). What I queried was:     "SELECT * FROM table WHERE *...some conditions on other columns...* AND A IS NULL OR A < B"

Comment: @DariaSmirnova For future reference, this could've been answered immediately if you included your query in your question.  By omitting the part of it that was responsible for the problem (additional conditions, which require the parenthesis around the provided conditions), no one could figure this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I queried was: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...some conditions on
>   other columns... AND A IS NULL OR A < B"

You should put the OR comparison in parenthesis:

```
...AND (A IS NULL OR A < B)
```

Comment: oh, right :) that totally solved the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE A = 'None' -- or (A IS NULL) ??
OR A < B
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the OP, columns A,B are timestamps. Therefore, the query should be similar to:

```
SELECT A,B
FROM table
WHERE A IS NULL
OR A < B;
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering you are using SQL server, if the datatype of A is varchar then

```
Select * 
from [table] 
where   (
  case when ISNUMERIC(A) = 1
  then cast (A as int)
  else 0
  end  
) < B
```

If int and nullable then

```
Select * from [table] where IsNull(A, 0) < B
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE 
  A IS NULL OR
  A < B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
A as A,
B as B 
FROM
YourTable
WHERE (A IS NULL OR A<B);
```

I know that you dont need to assign A and B but I think it is easier to understand for those who just started to learn SQL